# custom wrapper to a form api field

Tags: 7, forms

In form api, `#prefix` and `suffix` are not working for `'#type' => 'managed_file'`. Below is my code, is there any other way to wrap this?

```
    $form['cvFile'] = array(
    //'#title' => t('Upload your CV'),

    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    //'#description' => t('The uploaded file will be processed.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('cvFile', ''),

    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx'),
    '#prefix' => '<span class="row">',
    '#suffix' => '</span>'  
    ),

    '#upload_location' => 'public://cv/',
    '#process' => array('gng_job_my_cv_element_process'),

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using #prefix and #suffix is wrong. It should not be a part of #upload_validators array.

```
    $form['cvFile'] = array(
    //'#title' => t('Upload your CV'),

    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    //'#description' => t('The uploaded file will be processed.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('cvFile', ''),

    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx'),    
    ),

    '#prefix' => '<span class="row">',
    '#suffix' => '</span>',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://cv/',
    '#process' => array('gng_job_my_cv_element_process'),

    );
```

Check the form API for this : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix

Comment: Thanku @Nitesh, here I also need to add a `<span>` tag on choose file text that appear on a button. But I am not getting to only add  a wrapper to a text. Do you have any idea?